# curl command Chinese/Japanese url encode

Tags: python, linux, bash, curl

I want send a post request to a site.
The python code below works fine.

```
# -*- encoding=utf-8 -*-
import urllib, urllib2

url = "http://xxx.com/login.asp"
req = urllib2.urlopen(url, urllib.urlencode({"name":u"汉字".encode('GB2312'),"id":u"12345"}))
print req.read()
```

But the bash code return wrong page. Is this encoding problem or something else?

```
url="http://xxx.com/login.asp"
curl --data-urlencode "name=汉字&id=12345" $url
```

Comment: Suspicious lack of "GB2312" in the bash source detected.

Comment: what curl -v tells you?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [4]: urllib.urlencode({"name":"汉字".decode('utf-8').encode('GB2312'),"id":u"12345"})
Out[4]: 'name=%BA%BA%D7%D6&id=12345'
```

According to the curl man page,

```
--data-urlencode <data>
      ...
      The <data> part can be passed to
      curl using one of the following syntaxes:
      ...
      name=content
      This will make curl URL-encode the content part and pass that on.
      Note that the name part is expected to be URL-encoded already.
```

Since curl will URL-encode the content, we need to pass it a string which is not already URL-encoded:

```
In [7]: urllib.unquote(urllib.urlencode({"name":"汉字".decode('utf-8').encode('GB2312'),"id":u"12345"}))
Out[7]: 'name=\xba\xba\xd7\xd6&id=12345'
```

Therefore, try

```
url="http://xxx.com/login.asp"
curl --data-urlencode 'name=\xba\xba\xd7\xd6&id=12345' $url
```